# Reporting significance values for relative risk (RR) and number needed to treat (NNT)

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, relative-risk, medicine, number-needed-to-treat

I have calculated the relative risk & number needed to treat using the log-binomial regression model. NNT is calculated as the reciprocal of the marginal difference.

Does it make sense to report different p-values for the RR and the NNT?

Comment: https://www.cebm.net/2014/03/number-needed-to-treat-nnt/.  It does not seem like NNT is equivalent to RR, so why do you expect the p-values to be equal?